# Disjunction three ways

Tags: pyomo

I'd like to set up a constraint for a variable q.

```
(q <= -5) or (q == 0) or (q >= 5)
```

What's the best way of coding this?

```
def _d (disjunct, flag):
    model = disjunct.model()
    if flag == -1:
        disjunct.c = Constraint (expr=model.q <= -5)
    elif flag == 0:
        disjunct.c = Constraint (expr=model.q == 0)
    else:
        disjunct.c = Constraing (expr.model.q >= 5)

model.d = Disjunct ([-1,0,1], rule=_d)

def _c (model):
    return [model.d[-1], model.d[0], model.d[1]
model.c = Disjunction (rule=_c)
```

I'm not sure that's the right thing to do

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous ways to define disjunctions.  In the end, you want to end up with 3 `Disjunct` blocks defined, and a single `Disjunction` linking them.  Your approach is certainly valid (and has the benefit of working for both Abstract and Concrete models).  There are many other ways to end up at the same final state, including:

1) Explicit concrete disjuncts (Concrete models only):

```
model.d = Disjunct([-1,0,1])
model.d[-1].c = Constraint (expr=model.q <= -5)
model.d[0].c = Constraint (expr=model.q == 0)
model.d[1].c = Constraint (expr=model.q >= 5)
model.c = Disjunction(expr=[model.d[i] for i in (-1,0,1)])
```

1a) Explicit non-indexed concrete disjuncts (Concrete models only):

```
model.d1 = Disjunct()
model.d1.c = Constraint (expr=model.q <= -5)
model.d2 = Disjunct()
model.d2.c = Constraint (expr=model.q == 0)
model.d3 = Disjunct()
model.d3.c = Constraint (expr=model.q >= 5)
model.c = Disjunction(expr=[model.d1, model.d2, model.d3])
```

2) Implict Disjuncts (Concrete or Abstract models; since Pyomo 5.5):

```
def _c(m):
    return [m.q <= -5, m.q == 0, m.q >= 5]
model.c = Disjunction(rule=_c)
```

3) Implicit Disjuncts (Concrete only; since Pyomo 5.5)

```
model.c = Disjunction(expr=[model.q <= -5, model.q == 0, model.q >= 5])
```

Note that, as with @qi-chen's answer, you can enclose each Disjunct's constraint in another list (allowing you to specify multiple constraints for each disjunct):

```
model.c = Disjunction(expr=[[model.q <= -5, model.r <= -4],
                            [model.q == 0, model.r == 0],
                            [model.q >= 5, model.r >= 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

There's much simpler syntax now available, which will be updated in the Pyomo online documentation soon.

Assuming you've defined `model.q`, You can do:

`model.c = Disjunction(expr=[[model.q <= 5], [model.q == 0], [model.q >= 5]])`